# angularjs combine 2 objects by property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 different object arrays which i would like to merge according to the "id" value.

So if my first array looks like this:

```
[
  {
   "id": "75318408571184",
   "component": "textInput",
   "index": 0,
   "label": "Text",
   "description": "description",
   "placeholder": "placeholder",
   },
  {
  "id": "9463537670672",
  "component": "textArea",
  "index": 1,
  "label": "Paragraph",
  "description": "description",
  "placeholder": "placeholder"
  }
```

]

and my second one looks something like this:

```
[
  {
   "id": "75318408571184",
   "value": "value1"
   },
  {
  "id": "9463537670672",
  "value": "value2"
  }
```

]

i would like to get this array of objects:

```
 [
  {
   "id": "75318408571184",
   "component": "textInput",
   "index": 0,
   "label": "Text",
   "description": "description",
   "placeholder": "placeholder",
   "value": "value1"
   },
  {
  "id": "9463537670672",
  "component": "textArea",
  "index": 1,
  "label": "Paragraph",
  "description": "description",
  "placeholder": "placeholder",
   "value": "value2"
  }
```

]

is there a neat way to do this in angular or javascript without looping through the array?

Comment: Since i might be dealing with very large arrays i wanted something a little more efficient ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var result = firstArray.map(function(item) {
    var second = secondArray.find(function(i) {
        return item.id === i.id;
    });
    return second ? Object.assign(item, second) : item;
});
console.log(result);
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) applies function in argument on each item of `firstArray` and returns new array with modified values.

[Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is function which copies properties of `second` object to the `item` object in the code above.

Comment: Thanks, this works! just wondering if this is equally efficient to looping through the arrays  ?

Comment: Yes, map and find functions actually loop through array

Answer (score 2):

In plain Javascript, you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var obj1 = [{ "id": "75318408571184", "component": "textInput", "index": 0, "label": "Text", "description": "description", "placeholder": "placeholder", }, { "id": "9463537670672", "component": "textArea", "index": 1, "label": "Paragraph", "description": "description", "placeholder": "placeholder" }],
    obj2 = [{ "id": "75318408571184", "value": "value1" }, { "id": "9463537670672", "value": "value2" }];

obj2.forEach(function (a) {
    obj1.some(function (b) {
        if (a.id === b.id) {
            b.value = a.value;
            return true;
        }
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Another possibility is to build a hash table `temp` first and then manipulate the item directly.

```js
var obj1 = [{ "id": "75318408571184", "component": "textInput", "index": 0, "label": "Text", "description": "description", "placeholder": "placeholder", }, { "id": "9463537670672", "component": "textArea", "index": 1, "label": "Paragraph", "description": "description", "placeholder": "placeholder" }],
    obj2 = [{ "id": "75318408571184", "value": "value1" }, { "id": "9463537670672", "value": "value2" }],
    temp = {};

obj1.forEach(function (a, i) {
    temp[a.id] = i;
});
obj2.forEach(function (a) {
    obj1[temp[a.id]].value = a.value;
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Not very important but you shouldn't use document.write http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/2127296

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres, i have read it, but i do not understand the result.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are already good. But if you want to look at some other libraries you can have a look at this .
[loadash merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)

```
var object = {
  'fruits': ['apple'],
  'vegetables': ['beet']
};

var other = {
 'fruits': ['banana'],
 'vegetables': ['carrot']
};

_.merge(object, other, function(a, b) {
  if (_.isArray(a)) {
    return a.concat(b);
 }
});

// → { 'fruits': ['apple', 'banana'], 'vegetables': ['beet', 'carrot'] }
```